# Why does text inside TextSpan wrap when hardcoded but not when passed via an object

Tags: flutter, dart

So as the title says, the text will wrap instead of splitting words when it is hardcoded...but when the same string is passed via an object, it doesn't wrap...what am I missing?

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Zlbt.jpg)

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0nDM.jpg)

```
RichText(
  softWrap: true,
  text: TextSpan(
     text: "Synonyms:",
     style: TextStyle(
     color: Colors.white
      ),
     children: <TextSpan>[
        TextSpan(
        text: 
             "\n${wordOfTheDay.synonyms}",
              // text: '\nwall, rampart, fortification, parapet, stockade, palisade, barricade, embankment, earthwork',
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20.0,
            color: Colors.white70
            )
           ),
          ],
          ),
         )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have string key, in dart you can access them only like that: `object['stringKey']`..

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black38,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: MyHomePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  var wordOfTheDay = {
    'synonyms': '\nwall, rampart, fortification, parapet, stockade, palisade, barricade, embankment, earthwork'
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(wordOfTheDay);
    return Container(
        child: RichText(
      softWrap: true,
      text: TextSpan(
        text: "Synonyms:",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        children: <TextSpan>[
          TextSpan(
              text: '\n${wordOfTheDay["synonyms"]}',
              // text: '\nwall, rampart, fortification, parapet, stockade, palisade, barricade, embankment, earthwork',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white70)),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```